# Get href attribute from sibling's child jQuery?

Tags: jquery, href

I'm using the following code to try and get the href data from a another element, it keeps returning "undefined" what am I doing wrong?

```
$('.linkbutton').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var flagURL = $(this).siblings().next('.flag-action').attr('href');
        console.log(flagURL);
    });
<div class="linkbutton">
<h4 class="quoteflag">
    <a href="/demo/url/here" title=" " class="flag-action">
    </a>
</h4>
```

Comment: `siblings()` give you all elements from the same lvl as selected element, so you select `.linkbutton` try to select all elements from the same lvl and then select next element with flag-action class, read more about https://api.jquery.com/siblings/, and https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
var flagURL = $(this).siblings().next('.flag-action').attr('href');
```

try the below code:

```
var flagURL = $(this).siblings().find('.flag-action').attr('href');
```

Because next() selector will return you the next sibling. But you need the child of next sibling. Find() selector will give you all the descendants of a particular element. In your case, you can as well use children() selector instead of find() since you are trying to find immediate child of H4 element.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `.find()` and not `.next()` because that `flag-action` is a child and not an element next to your `quoteflag`

```js
$('.linkbutton').bind('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var flagURL = $(this).siblings().find(".flag-action").attr("href");
  console.log(flagURL);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linkbutton">click</div>
<h4 class="quoteflag">
  <a href="/demo/url/here" title=" " class="flag-action">
  </a>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `href` by using `find('.flag-action')` as `a` is a children of `.linkbutton` like:

```js
$('.linkbutton').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var flagURL = $(this).find('.flag-action').attr('href');
        alert(flagURL);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="linkbutton">Click here
<h4 class="quoteflagdiv">
    <a href="/demo/url/here" title=" " class="flag-action">
    </a>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.linkbutton').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var flagURL = $(this).siblings().find('.flag-action').attr('href');
        console.log(flagURL);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linkbutton">linkbutton div</div>
<h4 class="quoteflag">
    <a href="/demo/url/here" title=" " class="flag-action">
    </a>
</h4>
```